# I need my husband passport if I'm applying to a Tier 2 General Dependent Visa for UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, dependent-visa

I need my husband passport if I'm applying to a Tier 2 General Dependent Visa for UK? My husband already got his Tier 2 and He have his GRP but his passport expired, Can I apply to the visa  only with his GRP?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply with his expired passport. They will need that as well as the other supporting evidence for your application.